# Is it feasible to build a captive portal on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-wifi, captivenetwork

Is it feasible to make an app which works like a captive portal? So that user can make a Wifi hotspot and any other user connecting to it will be redirected to a Login page.

What I have already tried:

I made an app with following:

- Wifi hotspot
- Get list of connected users
- Made a login page
- Made a server on the Android device to host this web page.

How do I redirect the connected users to this webpage or do I have control over what the connected users can access?

Will this require Root access? or should this be done using NDK for lower level access?

Comment: did you found a solution to this problem?? @Metalhead1247

Comment: @HadyHallak i havent found anything yet

Comment: Root access may be required. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150207/captive-portal-on-android-device

Comment: Man how are u create login page ?and server on android device